# is this video representative of good technique for working with gas pipe

Tags: pipe, gas

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEdaICxZnug

Curious if you can 'horse' on the pipe that much and its ok.  More specifically, when he is tightening the pipe back together, he is moving the existing section alot.   Is that ok to not break the seals on the other side of that pipe ?

Also is that an appropriate amount of dope? Seems to be too much.

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, better to use adjustable wrench on the valve as not to deform the brass.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I watched the video, union's usually have a valve in front of them.  I am not sure what that gained other than showing the proper way to support the pipe (2 wrenches) to prevent the one side from unscrewing, did he over tighten it looked fine to me, as far as the dope he used I could not see if that was gas rated.
Can you use two much dope? Not really it is just a waste of $ and did you notice he wiped off most of the excess. I will also put my shutoff valve before the drip leg , the pipe hanging down and capped close to the point of use.
The drip leg is There to catch debris and moisture that is a really short one but some places don’t have lots of issues.  Being able to shut off the gas and clean the drip leg was a big deal at my last home we had a high moisture content due to our location on the line.

That video looked appropriate to me other than the union not having a shutoff and the same with the drip leg.